# Biblatex order of fields, e. g. remark before field URL

Tags: biblatex

How can I put an annotation directly in front of the field `URL`?
With

```
@book{Feynman2007_1_en,
  author       = {Feynman, R. P. and Leighton, R. B. and Sands, M.},
  title        = {Feynman Lectures on Physics},
  volume       = {1},
  publisher    = {Basic Books},
  year         = {2011},
  address      = {New York},
  note         = {All volumes available on the web},
  url          = {https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu},
  urldate      = {2021-02-14}
}
```

I get

[image]

In the biblatex documentation I did not find an appropriate field.
Maybe it's better not to use `@book`?
My MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliographie_Test.bib}

\begin{document}
This is from~\cite{Feynman2007_1_en}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` also has the field `addendum` for additional text. It is printed at the end of the entry after URL and `urldate`, so not exactly what you are looking for, but it might still be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution using the `usera` field and renewing the `doi+eprint+url` bibmacro:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @book{Feynman2007_1_en,
  author       = {Feynman, R. P. and Leighton, R. B. and Sands, M.},
  title        = {Feynman Lectures on Physics},
  volume       = {1},
  publisher    = {Basic Books},
  year         = {2011},
  address      = {New York},
  usera         = {All volumes available on the web},
  url          = {https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu},
  urldate      = {2021-02-14}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
  {\printfield{usera}\newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
 This is from~\cite{Feynman2007_1_en}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @moewe Thank you! I edited the answer